# Alternative to row_number to create a unique column in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase, row-number

### The problem

I have certain temporary tables to which I want to add a column with a unique identifier.

Ideally, I would like this column to contain incremental integers (e.g. 1,2,3,4, etc).

Alternatively, as a second best, I can settle for unique values, regardless of order (eg AAA, AAB, etc).

### My constraints

In Ms SQL I would typically do it with `row_number()`. Unfortunately, I am using a version of sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise 16) which doesn't seem to support `row_number()` nor `cross apply` .

### Reproducible example

The code below works in Ms SQL but not in Sybase. I have found loads of similar questions, but  all the answers rely on some variation of `row_number()`, which doesn't work for me. If I run it, I get

```
incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'
```

My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE #my_test (my_date datetime, my_value float NULL )

go

INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '1-Nov-2021',100
INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '2-Nov-2021',110
INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '3-Nov-2021',100
INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '4-Nov-2021',110
INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '5-Nov-2021',108
INSERT INTO #my_test SELECT '6-Nov-2021',105

go


select 
*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as my_id
from #my_test
```

Comment: What do your rows actually look like?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The main columns are something like: date, item, value1, value2, etc. Think of something like 10 apples sold on Monday for $3 and 15 pears sold on Tuesday for $8

Comment: I ask because if there is some (combination of) cols that could reasonably be unique, we can make an incrementing integer by joining a table to itself using `<` on those columns which causes a half cartesian explosion, which we then group and count, but it does depend on the data.. For your posted example, eg `select t1.my_date, count(*) FROM #my_test t1 JOIN #my_test t2 on t1.my_date < t2.my_date group by t1.my_date` - it's horrific, but it's also pretty basic SQL and works on even the most primitive of DBs. "desperate times...". I think I'd rather insert to another table with an autoint in

Comment: does ASE 16 support IDENTITY ?

Comment: Your statement "I have certain temporary tables to which I want to add a column with a unique identifier." implies the source data *does not* have a unique identifier. Is that correct? If so, why doesn't the source table have a primary key?

Comment: Excellent question - one I asked myself internally. The short answer is some of the underlying tables do not have a primary key. As for why - unfortunately, as is all too common in large organisation, whoever devised this is long gone, and getting clarity from those who should be responsible now is a challenge. Your opinion or mine is not going to change any of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `identity` column attribute is for, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #my_test
(my_id      int       identity      -- pick a data type that'll be big enough to hold all future values
,my_date    datetime
,my_value   float     NULL 
)
go

-- exclude identity column from INSERT (column_list):

INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '1-Nov-2021',100
INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '2-Nov-2021',110
INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '3-Nov-2021',100
INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '4-Nov-2021',110
INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '5-Nov-2021',108
INSERT INTO #my_test (my_date, my_value) SELECT '6-Nov-2021',105
go

select * from #my_test
order by my_date
go

 my_id       my_date                         my_value
 ----------- ------------------------------- ---------------------------
           1             Nov  1 2021 12:00AM                  100.000000
           2             Nov  2 2021 12:00AM                  110.000000
           3             Nov  3 2021 12:00AM                  100.000000
           4             Nov  4 2021 12:00AM                  110.000000
           5             Nov  5 2021 12:00AM                  108.000000
           6             Nov  6 2021 12:00AM                  105.000000
```

To add an identity column for a `select into`:

```
select  my_id2=identity(int),    -- define new identity column name and precision
        my_date,
        my_value
into    #my_test2
from    #my_test
order by my_date
go

select * from #my_test2
order by my_date
go

 my_id2      my_date                         my_value
 ----------- ------------------------------- ---------------------------
           1             Nov  1 2021 12:00AM                  100.000000
           2             Nov  2 2021 12:00AM                  110.000000
           3             Nov  3 2021 12:00AM                  100.000000
           4             Nov  4 2021 12:00AM                  110.000000
           5             Nov  5 2021 12:00AM                  108.000000
           6             Nov  6 2021 12:00AM                  105.000000
```

**NOTES:**

- OP will want to read up on identity gaps and identity burn factor
- primary issue is that if/when ASE is shutdown hard, upon starting up you'll see a significant gap between the last identity value and the new identify value
- see `identity_gap` setting for `create table` and `sp_chgattribute` (for altering identity attribute of a current table)
- for `select/into` see the `identity_gap` option
- above code tested in `ASE 16.0 SP04 GA`